# Nginx adds slash before PHP file argument

Tags: nginx, php, ghost-blog

This is a rewrite question, but it doesn't seem to be an issue with rewrites themselves--I've done all I can to try and research those.  I'm moving a website from a PHP-based structure to Ghost, and I'm trying to redirect URLS in the form of `example.com/blog/blog.php?postid=28` to `example.com/post-title-here/`.  However, whenever I try to access the first URL to test a rewrite solution, it only adds a slash immediately before the `?` and then proceeds to give me a 404.  I've noticed it does this without any `location`-based rules.  Is this what's preventing any rewrite solution from working?  If so, how do I stop it from doing so?

`example.com.conf`:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

Comment: @KienanKnight-Boehm please include the actual contents of your configuration file(s). It is very difficult to diagnose a possible misconfiguration without those.

Comment: I guess, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is pretty standard and we more interested in one that contains config for `example.com`. It's probably somewhere in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I did a little research on sites-enabled and the config info has now been separated into its own file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

Comment: @HBruijn Apologies.  Added the config file to the question.

Comment: There are no redirects shown here. What are you running on port 2368?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ghost.  The issue is that when I try to access a URL like `example.com/blog/blog.php?postid=28`, it adds a slash immediately before the question mark and then (I believe) passes it to Ghost, resulting in a 404.  This happened with and without various rewrite solutions I tried, so I'm attempting to figure out what the proper way to handle rewrites is to avoid adding in the extraneous slash.

Comment: Why do you think nginx is adding the slash? Again, there is no rule shown that would do that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I suppose it could be Ghost as well; I'm aware there's no rule causing it.  Regardless, I'm trying to figure out how a URL of the form I mentioned could be handled before even being passed to Ghost, rewritten, and _then_ passed to Ghost.  Having tried many other solutions that should have worked but all ran into the slash-before-question-mark problem, I posted asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to keep doing some research and answer my own question.  My config file (stored in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`) now looks like this:

```
map $query_string $updated_path {
        "postid=28"     "/proper-path-to-post/";
        "postid=27"     "/another-proper-path/";
        ...
}

server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     www.domain.*;

        location /blog/blog.php {
                rewrite ^/blog/blog.php $updated_path? permanent;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

I didn't realize that nginx takes any arguments to the URL (stuff after `?`) and stores it in the variable `$query_string`, so my earlier config was invalid.  The map block does basically what it says--maps cases of `$query_string` to what the proper path to the post should be.  Then, in the server block, the `/blog/blog.php` location rewrites any URLs to the proper path based on the arguments.  The `?` at the end of `$updated_path` tells nginx to not reappend the arguments passed to the URL.